# back button in ajax supported pages

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, history, back-button

i have a master php page and now i am loading different pages in a div of this master page using ajax. now i want to add a back button on the slave pages so that the div can loaded with its just previous slave page but the back button, i am using uses history.go(-1) that take me away from master page. has anybody any solution. Thanks in advance.

the code i am using is written below. but it is not working in ajax pages

```
<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Go back</a>
```

Comment: you might want to look at the history plugin

Comment: Did you try using links with '#' ? I.e, if you click a link that brings you to another slave page, it goes to http://your.site.com/page.php#slavename . I believe this will enable the history.go(-1) since your URL changes every time.

Answer (score 1):

Read [tutorial on Manipulating browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

It mentions:

- `pushState`, which is **used for creating "entries" in the browser's history** (with attached data about state), allowing to get back to some specific state you previously saved,
- `onpopstate` event, that **is fired when you go back or forth through the browser's history**, and passes information previously saved for specific entry in the history (so you actually can read data previously saved by `pushState` for this specific entry),

In case `pushState` and `onpopstate` do not work for you, there is still some ability to work on the basis of `onhashchange` event (however limited).

The good news is that what you want to achieve is definitely possible. It is even implemented in many famous sites such as Twitter, GitHub, Facebook etc.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions would be to use a framework for this purpose like [backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/)

Where you can setup routes just like on server side.

I feel this is the best way to do this on ajax sites.

Comment: You are suggesting major change of application's architecture in order to implement rather simple feature. Is not that an overkill?

Comment: Yes true , But in the long run it would be really beneficial if the application is to be fully ajax

Comment: "Is not that an overkill?" ..Yoda?

Comment: @Tim: I believe Yoda would say " _Overkill that is_ " or " _Overkill is not that?_ ". My "Is not that an overkill?" meant "Isn't that too much code for a simple task, [bro](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/bro)?". See more on [what _overkill_ means](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/overkill).

Comment: @GautamK: You may be right, but in the long term implementing whole libraries for simple tasks is not a good idea. To implement any library he needs to have good reasons first. [See this (caution: it is funny) about JS libraries / frameworks used for a simple task](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ERoHj.png)

Comment: @user1070433 : Ya you are right for really simple applications that are not going to expand not using frameworks like backbone is just plain easier. (Ps : The link was really funny)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the history functionality provided in newer browser. There is several libs that already provide functionality for you:

For JavaScript MVC applications:

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#History

For mobile web pages:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/pages/docs-navmodel.html

For implementing a solution your self:

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/